# Could Bardock really go ultra instinct?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

When Goku resorts to use Ultra Instinct *sign* against Gas (chapter 85), so that he does not need to make his heart calm, Gas seems startled at how he looks. He remembers Bardock having a similar aura:

[image: Goku using UI sign against Gas]

In the flashback fight (chapter 83), Bardock defeated Gas with something similar to UI sign, where he seemed immensly stronger than just a few seconds ago (when he was being beaten up).

So, could Bardock really go Ultra Instinct or is it just a resemblance?

The doubt arises because Bardock's eyes seemed just as normal (when compared to those of Goku in UI):

[image: Bardock and Goku have different eye colours]

Comment: Bardock can't, because he isn't the main character of the series, as for the drawing, you'll find almost all of the characters drawn similarly, except for their hairstyles.

Answer (score 1):

While they may look similar, recall that the principles of Ultra Instinct are fundamentally different from what Bardock does. To even achieve something like Ultra Instinct would require years of training by Bardock. If the Gods of Destruction are unable to use it there's no reason to believe Bardock could just "use it". This is probably closer to the " pseudo-ultra instinct" that Roshi displayed during the tournament of power if anything.

Comment: Well I did take that into the account, but Bardock's strength seemed similar to how Goku unlocked UI for the first to in Tournament of Power, i.e., by being forced to the limit of bringing _it_ out...

Comment: @SK-the-Learner DB characters, or saiyans in general, tend to break their limits a lot, that doesn't inherently prove its UI. Ultra Instinct is far from the on!y example of breaking in limits in DB

Answer (score 0):

Probably bardock already obtained the power of UI, as per Whis's statement, any living mere mortal, angel, kai can obtain UI. Even yamtcha and krillin, perhaps who break through their limits and keep pushing with the desire of do something will obtain UI, except destroyers. Destroyers had their own form called Ultra Ego.